# Cant deploy my xamarin Ios app to a different device with different apple id

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Im working with Xamarin developing a cross platform app. I have ios app that I can depoly into my device, and everything goes fine. When I try to deploy my app on a different device that associate to a different apple id I get the following error:"Launch failed. The app could not be launched on '... iPhone '. Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application on the device '...iPhone ': Your application failed code-signing checks.  Check your certificates, provisioning profiles, and bundle ids.   Probably your device is not part of the selected provisioning profile (error: 0xe800801)" 
I'm try to define provisioning profile for the apple id that connected to the other device, but I can't. I'm getting the error : "the app id "...." cannot be registered to your development team. change your bundle identifier to a unique string and try again" but when I create a provisioning profile for other bundle identifier I keep getting the first message. What should I do to run my app on a different device with different apple id? 
Thanks.

Comment: use the SAME apple id - login to your dev account, add the 2nd device, and then regenerate your provisioning profile with BOTH devices selected

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, Im using the free provisioning user for apple developer, so in the apple developer site I cant access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles @Jason

Comment: Are you changing the team in your project settings when you change the bundle ID?  Are you using automatic code signing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a device to provision profile. Since you are using free provisioning, try automatic problem resolving. If that does not help, maybe you hit the limit of free devices (3 devices). Then you need to contact Apple so they remove devices from your account. Or just register one more account and use it to put a version on that device.